# Ubuntu 12.04 Eclipse Indigo wont start

Tags: eclipse, ubuntu, ubuntu-12.04

Please help :( My Eclipse Indigo wont launch. It shows the small blue rectangle and then hangs on that. If I then bring another window infront of this the blue square is now grey. There is no error and there is no error log file in the .eclipse folder.

My Ubuntu 12.04 has been acting funny. The software installer doesnt work and there are errors in the update manager. I finally did command line -update using apt-get and since then my eclipse has been broken.

System :

Ubuntu 12.04 X 64

java -version

java version "1.7.0_11" Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_11-b21) Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 23.6-b04, mixed mode)

Comment: Try to run it from the command line (just type `eclipse` and hit enter) a past what is printed in the console, please.

Comment: is this Eclipse which comes from Ubuntu's repositories? If so, have you tried extracting/running Eclipse after downloading from Eclipse's main site?

Comment: Try downloading from Eclipse's website, extract, and run directly from the extracted directory.  You might be able to determine if your errors are based on Java or on Ubuntu's Eclipse package.  BTW, I've been burned by the packaged Eclipse in Ubuntu's repositories in the past, so I only use versions directly downloaded from Eclipse's site.

Comment: So I downloaded eclipse Juno from the eclise.org site. Extracted it out and then chose my old workspace as the workspace to use. And now its hanging on the small window of Juno  now too....

Comment: ACtually Juno just loaded. IT took about 5 mins to load.

Comment: Thanks for your help. How do I accept your comment as an answer?

Comment: @Spunog, I wrote up an actual post which you can mark as an answer if you so wish.  Glad you got up and running!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've been burned in the past by the Eclipse package bundled in Ubuntu's repositories.  I would recommend downloading directly from Eclipse's website and run from there.

If you're having problems launching the Ubuntu-version, extracting and running manually should give you some indication that the problem is with Java or Eclipse.

Comment: Thanks. I didnt realize I could just untar the app and it woudl work out of the box like that. I was worried I had lost all my project configs.